# How can I align my text to center while using float: left;

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a simple website but I can't align my unordered list's navigation bar to the center.. I positioned "Contact Us" to be in the right cause that's where I want it to be and I want the rest of the 3 to be in the center but I cannot align it for some reason .. Please help me.. Any help would be greatly appreciated...Here's the code:

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>NavBar</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="nav">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="nav">About us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="nav">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="contact">Contact us</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  background-color: Aqua;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li a {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background: black;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  margin: 25px;
  color: orange;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
a:hover {
  color: white;
}

#contact {
  position: relative;
  left: 780px;
}
```

Comment: using float is gone days now, you still want to use that? you say `contact us` to be at left or right ?

Comment: You can solves same problem using flex.  using flex is quite easy

Comment: If you want me to solve using flex, then please comment back. I will solve it for you

Comment: @Manjuboyz Oh sorry I meant right, My bad ... Is there any way I can align that to the right and at the same time the other 3 to the center?

Comment: @FerinPatel Sure, Please... I would really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see output in full screen mode.

```css
ul
{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-evenly;
  align-items:center;
}
.center-items
{
  width:75%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
.center-items li
{
  padding:0px 50px;
  list-style:none;
}
.right-items li
{
  list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>NavBar</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <div class="center-items">
      <li><a href="#" class="nav">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav">About us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav">Products</a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="right-items">
      <li><a href="#" id="contact">Contact us</a></li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is there any way I can move them a little to the left

Comment: you can play with center-item class width

Answer (score 1):

You can use `float: right` instead of `left: 780px;`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  background-color: Aqua;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li a {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background: black;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  margin: 25px;
  color: orange;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
a:hover {
  color: white;
}

#contact {
  position: relative;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>NavBar</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="nav">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="nav">About us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="nav">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="contact">Contact us</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much .. but how do I make Home, About us, Products align to the center of the page?

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  background-color: Aqua;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex; /*Flexbox*/
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
}

li a {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background: black;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  color: orange;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
a:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="nav">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="nav">About us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="nav">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="contact">Contact us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Used flexbox and removed float